# Difficulties with playing YouTube videos in Big Sur beta in Safari

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, youtube, big-sur

I was trying to play YouTube videos in Safari v14.0 (16610.1.23.1.3) in Big Sur beta, but it doesn't work, playing window is black and after click into it I get a message that an error occured. Does someone has solution for this one?

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys, I solve the problem. It was causing AdBlock extension for Safari, I uninstalled it and installed AdGuard and now it works like a charm.

Comment: It‘s a beta version, so please make the developer of the plugin aware of the issue.

Comment: That's actually something Google has recently changed & all the ad blockers are rushing to catch up.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for a new info :)

Comment: I'm getting this error on many youtube videos, but I don't have a single extension installed in Safari. Big Sur beta (20A5364e).